# Is a joining table needed for a very basic many to many relationship in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two models which could be called Post and Category.

Category has many posts and Post has many categories. From what I have seen I can either use `has_many through` with a joining table or `has_and_belongs_to_many` I have seen online that this is generally unfavorable.

Because of how simple this relationship is would I want to create a joining table here or would I be fine just creating an array of category_ids on Post? What would be the pros and cons of both?

Comment: Seriously, just do the joining table. It's the right answer. It's conventional. It's easier. Don't over think it.

Comment: join the tables, lets Active record do the work, don't implement something which is cumbersome and not really needed :)